# Window.open opening tab instead of popup in Opera?

Tags: javascript, popup, opera

I'm simply opening a popup from JavaScript with the settings you can see in the code. Works fine in Firefox. In Opera it's opening it in a new tab instead. Why?

Here's a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hafWs/3/

The number of parameters doesn't seem to make a difference. Either work in Firefox and IE8. (Don't have IE9 or Chrome to test right now.)

I tried googling... can't find anything. I don't even see anything here that mentions it, yet it's clearly working in their examples: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The Opera forums are currently down but some Googling brought me this -> http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/238680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with spaces in options param:

```
window.showPopup = function(){
    window.open(
        'http://placekitten.com/600/500',
        'thePopup',
        'width=600,height=500' /* <------- Look, no spaces and works */
    );
}
```

It is still a tab, but with different dimensions. So, it looks kinda as popup.

Comment: Oh... thanks! Working now. But, uh... I was sure I already tested that. I must have done something stupid like opened the test in Firefox instead of opera by accident, then reverted it thinking that wasn't the case. Heh. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the browser itself (preferences) and cannot be changed from JavaScript.

NOTE: I've seen some posts that say you can determine whether the window opens in a tab or as a new window based on the parameters that you pass the window.open function. I have never seen this work consistently.

Comment: Well, the thing is, the quirksmode.org page has a working example, which I can see works fine in opera. I looked at the source and can't tell what I might be doing differently from it in my test code. Seems to be passing variables to the window.open function no differently than I am.

Comment: What's the URL for the quirksmode example?

Comment: You mean the link to the example, or the URL of the popup it opens? The link is in the details of this question above.

I thought about the URL of the popup being opened possibly causing it, but that's not the case. I mean, it could've made a difference whether the popup was the same domain or not, but I tested that, and that's not the problem, apparently.